# Finding a Prime Using Sin Function

Tags: prime-numbers, factoring

To find if n is prime, take the square root of n, called m. Let O be the set of primes less than or equal to m. For every element o in O, let y = sin⁡(πx/o), for all real numbers x from zero to n. So that an integer less than or equal to n, will have a zero if and only if that integer is composite, or the first zero in the function and prime. If none of the functions of y equal zero for any o at n, then n is prime. Does this work as a way to find primes?

Comment: In $\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{o}\right)$ you are going to divide $n$ by all the $o$s and then do something more complicated.  Seeing whether $\frac{n}{o}$ is ever an integer (i.e. has no remainder) some other way might be easier (and very different approaches might be better for large $n$), but your way would work on the  assumption you can do the calculations with enough precision.

Comment: Interesting! Thank you.